# Oauth2 Authentication with React Native

Tags: react-native, express, authentication, oauth-2.0, passport.js

i am trying to add authentication to my app using OAuth2 & also secure the back-end so only logged in users can access it.

Im just trying to wrap my head around the process and some clarification would be great. To my understanding here is how i would do it.

1. User logs in with oauth2 provider in app.
2. App sends the returned code to the back-end.
3. back-end fetches access token and returns to the app to be saved.

now, for all secure requests. I send the accesstoken as a parameter to the back-end which checks if it is valid or not.

would this be the correct way of creating a secure dashboard type app with oauth2?

thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct except that in step 2 you send the authorization code back to the OAuth2 provider - as part of an authorization code grant message.

Here's an example of the message workflow during a user session. For a mobile app the same OAuth messages are used:
https://authguidance.com/2018/01/18/desktop-app-technical-workflow/

If it helps there are some code samples of mine to demo this behaviour - it is tricky to implement though:
https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/